# Como colocar para funcionar o menu em modo responsivo em bootstrap

Tags: html

Aqui está o código colocado para quando redimensionar o browser para poder aparecer o site responsivo as o menu não aparece quando clicar não faz nada

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="menu">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header"> 
            <a href="#" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> 
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </a> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 visible-lg ">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DADOS</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">APLICAÇÃO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PROGRAMADORES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o que você tentou fazer, assim fica mais fácil ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você precisa de um menu bootstrap, então fiz o seguinte exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaketaylor/84mqazgq/

O codigo é este:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
        <a href="#" class="hidden-xs">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Home</a>
        </li>
                <li>
        <a href="#products" class="hidden-xs">Products</a>
        <a href="#products" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#overview" class="hidden-xs">Overview</a>
        <a href="#overview" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Overview</a>
        </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
```

Você pode substituir por seu codigo, é necessario também inserir o bootstrap para uso em seu projeto assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Você pode ler mais aqui:
http://getbootstrap.com.br/components/#dropdowns